# Custom ViewGroup, GridView, and SimpleCursorAdapter

Tags: android, gridview, simplecursoradapter

I need to display data in 3 textviews, inside each grid item, but also I want each grid item to be square. Also the cursoradapter is all based on a search.

Based on my necessities I found by research that I should be creating my own viewgroup for each grid item and setting the height to be the same as the width (in onMeasurement), which produces proper squares. But now my data from the cursoradapter will not show up in the views.

I can tell that the cursoradapter is being referenced because the number of white boxes in the gridview changes depending on what I search.

Where am I going wrong?

```
<ubiquia.sqbxsync.main.GridViewGroup
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="#ffffff">

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/gridLayout"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="#ffffff">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:text="TextView"
        android:textSize="15dp"
        android:textColor="#ff000000" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:text="TextView"
        android:textSize="11dp"
        android:textColor="#ff000000" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:text="TextView"
        android:textSize="11dp"
        android:textColor="#ff000000" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

```
package ubiquia.sqbxsync.main;

import android.content.Context;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

public class GridViewGroup extends ViewGroup {

    public GridViewGroup(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onLayout(boolean changed, int l, int t, int r, int b) {
     // Do nothing   
    }

    @Override
    protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
        super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, widthMeasureSpec);
    }  
}
```

My CursorAdapter

```
public class GridCursorAdapter extends CursorAdapter {

    public GridCursorAdapter(Context context, Cursor c) {
        super(context, c);
    }

    @Override
    public View newView(Context context, Cursor cursor, ViewGroup parent) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View gridView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.grid_item, null, true);
        return gridView;
    }

    @Override
    public void bindView(View view, Context context, Cursor cursor) {
        TextView tv1 = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        TextView tv2 = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textView2);
        TextView tv3 = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textView3);
        tv1.setText(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("trackingnumber")));
        tv2.setText(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("recipient_name")));
        tv3.setText(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("carrier_name")));
    }
}
```

Comment: The `onLayout()` method is responsible for placing the children in the parent's area and as you didn't implement it...

Comment: What I am saying is that the children are being placed properly.. Just the content is not being placed in the children. From the android documentation it says onLayout is used for positioning and sizing of children and I have already sized them in onMeasure.

Comment: I am confused on how to apply my cursoradapter to the textviews in the ViewGroup @Luksprog

Comment: You create your own adapter.

Comment: Okay, now that I have my own adapter, how do I use these two together? I am not understanding how my main activity creates the adapter, and then somehow instantiates the view. Wouldn't I have to pass the cursor to my viewgroup somehow? @Luksprog

Comment: It seems my first advice was helpful after all. The adapter will be used like you did, setting it on the ListView.

Comment: No, because using the super.onLayout(changed,l,t,r,b); did not work when I was extending the ViewPager, I had to change it to a LinearLayout which I did completely from seeing another completely irrelevant example. Thanks for the attempt though.

Comment: You should really read about custom components.

Comment: I thought the purpose of StackOverflow was to come here when you already tried to read the tutorials and documentation and still did not understand, that is why I asked this question. Thank you for the advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that after changing my extends to LinearLayout and writing in the super.onLayout(changed,l,t,r,b); it now shows my layout in the square that I wanted.